# AWS EC2 web server no access after a while

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've followed the guide to set up a LAMP WordPress site with EC2 on a Linux machine. I've attached a Elastic IP to it and configured the Security Group to allow HTTP access. It works great to access globally. However, after about one hour, I can't access the site any more. The EC2 health checks are fine, I can SSH to the server and the httpd, MySQL etc is up and running. When I reboot the EC2, everything starts to work again.

I've tried to troubleshoot for a while but don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked your `httpd` logs and `syslog` when this happens? Have you tried to do a local `curl` on the machine to see if it responds to requests locally?

Comment: Nice one, I'll check as soon as it stops responding @birryree

Comment: What is the configuration of your EC2 and what is the web server u r running ? Might be a resource issue (RAM, storage).

Comment: Are you using a t2 instance? If so, are you running out of CPU credits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same with t2.micro with Apache and MySQL running on 8 GB Storage. Reasons is the memory consumption and log file filled the storage. This might be the reason here.